# PHP Not writing text to txt file windows server 2012 R2

Tags: php

I am trying to add text to txt file via php in new production server that is not inserting if the same am trying on my local machine that happens and i have given all permission to the folder in server though that is not saving this sound funny i tried all possible ways that google says still not working

```
    <?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file! " . var_export(error_get_last(), true));
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

output error with in the directory

```
   PHP Warning:  fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test.in\httpdocs\Test.php on line 2
```

error for different drive

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(E:\Log
ewfile.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/test.in\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test.in\httpdocs\Test.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  fopen(E:\Log
ewfile.txt): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test.in\httpdocs\Test.php on line 2
```

Comment: Just for clarification: the code runs into the `or die("Unable to open file!")` "condition"?

Comment: @VolkerK yes correct  but my point is how to give php a access to write text to file

Comment: For debugging purposes: Can you please use `or die("Unable to open file! " . var_export(error_get_last(), true));` and [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35865591/edit) the output to your question text? (maybe edit the actual path, if you feel that it reveals to much of your server)

Comment: does the file exist? If not, have you tried `fopen("newfile.txt", "w+")`? Also: does the log file have an entry for this?

Comment: @harpax: What's the advantage of `w+` in case the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @VolkerK u can c i have updated my answer

Comment: Can you please also update the code? Looks like now you have possibly a parse error....

Comment: @VolkerK done u can check now

Comment: @VolkerK: good point -- nevermind

Comment: Hm. The code looks ok. Maybe your php version doesn't have error_get_last() or you're not allowed to access it. Maybe a more verbose version will shed some light on the issue: https://3v4l.org/jfFfp

Comment: @VolkerK i have updated my error can you solve that now

Comment: The error message says it all, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: @VolkerK thanks for the reply but what can be done to solve that

Comment: Do you have access to the configuration files (i.e. can you adjust them)?

Comment: @VolkerK yes i doo please let me know what to do

Comment: Check either the output of `<?php phpinfo();` or `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` to see which php.ini you should edit. Open that file and search for open_basedir, add a directory where you want to write your output to, re-start the iis (or w3c service)  and then use that directory in your script `fopen("path/to/allowed/directory/newfile.txt", "w")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105691/discussion-between-shaik-and-volkerk).

Comment: can you join me on chat there are already 2 directory i can share you the image

Comment: @VolkerK gives me error PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why your PHP script might not be able to write to the filesystem. The most common one is a permissions issue: the user that your Web server runs as does not have permission to write to the directory in question.

Another reason why you might not be able to write to files is that some service providers in my experience disable file I/O functions in the `php.ini` file using the [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive. You would have to get the administrator of the server to change this for you.

Comment: i personally feel the same problem of permission what exactly has to be changed in the php.ini if u specify that can be use full